# How to add data derived from source code file name or content to a resource at build time

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, ant

**Background**

I'm adding database migrations to an existing project using the open source project mongobee.  The actual migrations are all handled by mongobee and its concepts of changelogs and changesets.  Part of this enhancement involves checking the current MongoDB database migration version at runtime and comparing it against the version expected by the java application.  The reasoning behind this is we'd like to have an installation of our product download code updates (new *.wars) and upon logging in the new version of the application, the admin user would be prompted to update the database if their database version is lower than expected.

We're currently using Maven to package and build our software.

**Problem**

The one area that's nagging me is how to handle tagging the database version the Java source code expects.  I'd like to avoid manually entering this each time we do a build and add a migration.

My proposed solution may not be ideal.  My initial thought is to use a convention for the changelog file and class names like "v0001_first_migration" and then at build time, use maybe the maven AntRun plugin to call a separately compiled java file that traverses the migration changelog directory and looks for the latest migration number and then stores that result in a resource file, probably XML.  The application can then read that XML file at runtime to get the database version it expects.

1 - Is this feasible?

2 - Is there a way to do something like this in pure Maven without using AntRun?

3 - Is there another option to accomplish this easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to my proposed solution above, I used a reflection project found here: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections and iterated through all of the classnames in my migrations directory that follow the aforementioned convention (v0001_first_migration, v0002_second_migration).  I parse those using regex to get an Integer and do comparisons to determine the migration version expected by the app.  The database side was a lot easier so I won't go over that.

Now, instead of using Ant tasks I'm just popping the expected app migration version into a singleton (gross I know) or alternatively just calling the function that finds the expected app migration depending on where it's used.

WHY a Singleton?  The parsing process is expensive and I expect to use this data on each REST call that wants to touch our database.  In the REST layer I created the singleton because of some limitations with our current project.  The better way here is in the case of Tomcat, create a ServletListener and assign the migration version as an attribute of the ServletContext.  Due to the way our REST layer works, I'd be modifying a TON of function signatures to pass in the @Context ServletContext.  We don't have Dependency Injection containers either so my options were limited if I didn't want to touch almost every action in the REST layer.  The Singleton gets the expected app migration version at startup and that's it so it's still easy to test with mocks and there are no concurrency issues that I can see.